# Issue when I selected Arabic language

Tags: android

I have working on multi supported Language App,

When I working on English, all are Good but When I switch Language from `EN` to `AR` then username starts from `LTR` & Phone starts with `RTL`.

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/etUserName"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
       android:background="@null"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:hint="@string/username"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:gravity="start"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
       android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
       android:background="@null"
       android:hint="@string/phone_number"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:inputType="phone"
       android:maxLength="10"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:gravity="start"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
       android:textSize="16sp" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed My Own Question's Answer as below, I just added `android:textAlignment="viewStart"` & `android:gravity="start"` to fix.

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/etUserName"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:hint="@string/username"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:textAlignment="viewStart"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
      android:textSize="16sp" />
```